# how to use dropdown virtualScroll in primeng 6

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown, primeng

I have a dropdown with 100+ elements loaded dynamically from angular function in particular conditions.

This loading takes several seconds. No http calls are pending, this time is used by priming component (dropdown) for delete and create elements (options).

I would to try use new functionality virtualScroll present in primeng v7.

My project has angular 4.x and primeng v6. I haven't found basics requirements for primeng 7. I tried to upgrade to project 7 but project still broken.

Is there documentation for the migration from primeng 6 to primeng 7? Or is there possibilities to use virtualscroll with primeng 6?

Answer (score 1):

You can update like this..

1st method:

```
uninstall the previous version as npm uninstall primeng

then reinstall it like npm install primeng
```

2nd method:

```
npm update primeng
```